# Swagger is not able to take in a Map as a request type

Tags: java, swagger

I am using Swagger, however, when I make my post call to the service I keep getting the following error and I am not sure what I am missing in terms of my properties/code.

`Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'data'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property`

```
public class Control {
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, consumes = {
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<Response> upload(@ModelAttribute final UploadModel model) {
        var response = service.uploadFile(model);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}
    
public class UploadModel {

    private String id;
    private MultipartFile file;
    private Map<String, Object> data;

}
```

I pass the following in swagger to my map data type:

```
{
  "additionalProp1": {},
  "additionalProp2": {},
  "additionalProp3": {}
}
```